# How to properly set up a media player javafx

Tags: java, javafx, media-player, scrollpane, pause

I have created a media player method is javafx which is called upon startup (below is the media player). My problem is that this pauses whenever I interact with a scroll pane by dragging or by zooming the player pauses and does not start again. Why is this the case and how may I fix this(included full application if you would to try it).

Method(Live code)

```
    private static void MusicPlayer() {
    if(musicList.peek() == null)
    {
        return;
    }
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(new Media(new File(musicList.poll()).toURI().toString()));
    mediaPlayer.setOnReady(() -> {
        mediaPlayer.play();
        mediaPlayer.setOnEndOfMedia(() -> {
            mediaPlayer.dispose();
            MusicPlayer();
        });
    });
}
```

Minimal

```
package minimalist;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Minimal extends Application{

    private static Queue<String> musicList = new LinkedList<String>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        List<String> result = Files.find(Paths.get(".\\music"), 100,
                (p, a) -> p.toString().toLowerCase().endsWith(".mp3"))
                .map(path -> path.toString())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        for(int a = 0; a < result.size(); a++)
        {
            musicList.add(result.get(a));
        }
        MusicPlayer();
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        ScrollPane scrollpane = new ScrollPane();
        Image image = new Image("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/70/Kusatma_Zonaro.jpg");
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(image);
        scrollpane.setContent(imageView);
        scrollpane.setPannable(true);
        Scene scene = new Scene(new StackPane(scrollpane));
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setFullScreen(true);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private static void MusicPlayer() {
        if(musicList.peek() == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(new Media(new File(musicList.poll()).toURI().toString()));
        mediaPlayer.setOnReady(() -> {
            mediaPlayer.play();
            mediaPlayer.setOnEndOfMedia(() -> {
                mediaPlayer.dispose();
                MusicPlayer();
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look here https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/media/playercontrol.htm .Adam the code you are offering is too big .. try to find the position where the bug is coming from so we can offer a solution.Also try to build your project with fxml that will reduce a lot your main code.

Comment: You've tried to ask this [before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39969156/music-player-pauses-upon-interaction-with-interface-javafx). It would really help if you created a [MCVE] for this: your first attempt to ask did not contain *complete* code; the code in this question is certainly not *minimal* (and is not really complete either, since it depends on resources we don't have). So create a new project that *just* has the code to play music and something to drag and see if you can reproduce the problem. Then post the smallest complete application that shows the issue.

Comment: @GoXR3Plus Yeah I looked at that before posting this and it wasn't terribly useful. Below I have posted a minimal all you need to do is create a project and add a source folder named music that contains mp3 files.

Comment: @James_D Yes I know that I have posted this before, however I did not recieve and answer and find that forums don't like it when you revive dead threads. Updated the question to include a minimal, create a project and add a source folder names music that contains mp3 files in order to test the issue.

Comment: I have trouble getting anything to play at all the way you have it coded. Is there a reason you want to start the music looping in `main`, instead of from `start()`? You shouldn't really be doing anything in the `main` method in a ("pure") JavaFX application other than calling `launch()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This all seems to behave in something of a fragile manner.

I would not recommend launching the media player from the `main` method. The documentation is a bit lacking on threading policy for `MediaPlayer`, but since you are launching a regular JavaFX application it would seem sensible to follow the usual rules and only call methods on it from the JavaFX Application Thread. On my system, I was unable to get any music playing the way you had it set up.

I also had sporadic issues getting it to start playing after changing that; I guessed that maybe I was leaving system resources tied up after exiting, so I modified the code to ensure the player was disposed when the application ended. After both those changes, it behaved as expected. At no point though did I have any issues associated with user input; my guess is that these are caused by launching the media player from the main thread instead of from the FX Application Thread, and are probably system-dependent.

Here's the code that worked fine for me. I also cleaned up some of the redundancy in your code (iterating through `Path`s to convert them to `String`s which you then convert back to `File`s so you can convert to a string representation of a URL seems somewhat circuitous; you also create a completely unnecessary list in that process, etc) and renamed things so that it abides by proper [naming conventations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java)):

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Minimal extends Application{

    private Queue<Path> musicList = new LinkedList<>();

    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer ;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        // Everyone should have this album. Edit the path if your musical taste is poor.
        Files.find(Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home"),"Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Music/Thievery Corporation/Saudade/"), 100,
                (p, a) -> p.toString().toLowerCase().endsWith(".m4a"))
                .forEach(musicList::add);

        playMusic();

        ScrollPane scrollpane = new ScrollPane();
        Image image = new Image("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/70/Kusatma_Zonaro.jpg");
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(image);
        scrollpane.setContent(imageView);
        scrollpane.setPannable(true);
        Scene scene = new Scene(new StackPane(scrollpane));
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setFullScreen(true);
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
            mediaPlayer.dispose();
        }
    }

    private void playMusic() {
        if(musicList.peek() == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(new Media(musicList.poll().toUri().toString()));
        mediaPlayer.setOnReady(() -> {
            mediaPlayer.play();
            mediaPlayer.setOnEndOfMedia(() -> {
                mediaPlayer.dispose();
                playMusic();
            });
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this worked though apparently I have bad musical taste...earlier I tried moving the code to the start method however it did not change anything the time I tried it so I moved it back to the main method.